# How long does it take for a question that is assigned a bounty to appear as featured?

Tags: discussion, bounties

I just put in a 50+ bounty on a question I had, but I don't see it listed under the features tab.  The bounty icon is showing up on the two answers I had before however.

Does it take more than a few hours to show up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, now it's in the list...so I guess something between five and fifteen minutes.

Answer (score 1):

It should be there (almost) instantly (caching aside). It's showing up on the [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell), [featured tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell) for me, and I'm sure it's on the [main featured tab](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=featured), but I'm not about to scan through the 300 questions/ 21 pages to find it!