# How long does it take for bounty to get featured?

Tags: support, bounties

Is there a real human in SO to manually approve and assign bounty questions to get featured? I have put a +400 bounty on my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17029780/how-to-display-mathjax-formula-from-hard-coded-string-equation) but it just doesn't appear anywhere in the tagged or featured bounty list. In that similar [discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111683/how-long-does-it-take-for-a-question-that-is-assigned-a-bounty-to-appear-as-feat) they said the guess is around 15 min, but now it's been over an hour and it is still nowhere to be seen.

You won't understand how unsettling this is if this is not your first bounty and not your first time losing 400 reps and you're not urgently need help on the question. I will keep the timing and update this post to let you know how long it takes to get my bounty featured.

EDIT: After the downvote and the claimed status-norepro, this is what I see in my screen:
[image]

I double-checked, it is still currently the same.

SOLUTION:

It's hidden in the last entry second page. I have been naive to assume that new entry will always come out at top. Thanks hims056 for pointing this out.

Comment: I can see your question in [the featured tab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mathjax?sort=featured&pagesize=50).

Comment: It is also appeared in the featured tab [tagged android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android?page=2&sort=featured&pagesize=50) (the last one)

Comment: Also appeared in [the featured tab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions?page=8&sort=featured&pagesize=50) without any filter. (the second last)

Comment: That is weird. I already cleared and restarted my browser. Is this a server update issue?

Comment: I don't think so. How were you searching in the featured tab?

Comment: But did you navigate to the second page?

Comment: Ah, I think I misunderstand the ordering of the bounty list. I thought the latest bounty will always show in the first page. Now I see my bounty --last entry-- in the SECOND page!

Comment: [Sorting order of featured questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91034/)

Answer (score 1):

That's a [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro). I can see your question in the featured tab (both the general, and the tag).

In any case, remember that everything in Stack Overflow is aggressively cached, so it may take a few minutes for such actions to get displayed.

Comment: See edit. Please slow down and read before taking any judgment. If they're caching it then they are really aggresively caching it for over an hour.

Comment: First of all, it's possible (yes, Bounties aren't that common, so there might be some aggressive cache over them). Also, check the second page of the android tag featured questions. In the general list, the order is *random*, but that's not the case with the tag list.

Comment: Yes, I finally see it at the bottom of second page. Thank you.

Comment: Glad you could find it :)